# Force hr to start outside of parent container

Tags: html, css

I got some HTML code looking like this

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- SOME OTHER CONTEN HERE -->
  <hr>
  <!-- SOME OTHER CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
```

The class container got a width of 90% and I want the hr to go from side-to-side of the screen. To give the hr the correct width i use width: 100vw but the it will still start where the .container class starts, I tried to solve this by using margin-left: -10% but this does not work on all different resolutions, I have also tried position absloute and left: 0 but this messed up the flow of the content that is above and under it.

```
.container {
  width: 90%
}

hr {
 width: 100vw;
}
```

How can i make sure that hr go side-to-side of the screen without messing up the flow of the content above and under it?

Comment: Could you just close the container tag before the HR and re-open it afterwards? Forcing elements to expand outside their parent tends to be best avoided if not strictly necessary, imho.

Comment: That was my first thought. But what I did not mention is that this part of the html is nested far down in the html. Some of the parents are for example bs rows and cols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would apply the following CSS to `hr` that hides the `hr` and make a `:after` pseudo element to take the effect, using `left` and `transform` is to avoid the `:after` exceed the page width and causing a horizontal scroll

```
hr { margin-bottom: 1px; height: 0; border: 0; position: relative; }
hr:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 50%; // Positioning
  height: 1px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #e5d5d5;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); // Positioning
  transform: translateX(-50%); // Positioning
}
```

Try on: https://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/n16uysLn/

Answer (score 0):

in this case, I would use `position: absolute` for the `<hr>`

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/zKAXLk

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- SOME OTHER CONTEN HERE -->
  <hr>
  <!-- SOME OTHER CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

hr {
 width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
}
```

for an element with `position: absolute` who has a parent with `position: relative`, it will absolutely position itself within its parent.

the `top: 110%` will position it 10% lower than the bottom of the div

you will need to add extra margin-bottom to the `<div>` to avoid the `<hr>` overlapping with the element under the `<div>`